# Doubling weights

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am trying to prove that the fonction $|x|^a$ is a doubling weight for
$a>0$, i.e., there exists a constant $C_0$ such that for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and
for all $r>0$, we have
$\int_{B(x,2r)}|y|^ady \le C_0\int_{B(x,r)}|y|^ady$.

I have already proved for the case when $x=0$, I only applied radial coordinates.
However, for the general case, I don't know.
I have the hint to consider the case $|x|>3r$
but I don't know how use it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is $B(x, r)$ the beta function or something else?

Comment: it's only  the ball of center $x$ and radius $r$,